# TFS 2010 - exclude specific files on deploy, based on environment?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, build-automation, robots.txt

Using VS 2010 and TFS 2010.

Is there a way to exclude certain files from a build definition / deploy, based on the environment that I am deploying to?

The primary purpose of this is to exclude a robots.txt file from the dev / QA deploys, but leave it in place for production.

Note: I have web config set up with different configurations for different environments, using the web.config transforms, but this is the only 'environment specific' thing I've found so far.

Comment: How are you deploying? Do you have dev / QA / Prod domains or is everthing on the same domain? for example, we use Wix to package the code and we have distinct domains for dev, QA and Prod. This way we can package different versions of files such as config files e.g. dev.web.config / prod.web.config and the MSI generated by wix will deploy the appropriate file depending on which domain the installer is running in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - we are deploying with the build definition file (right click, deploy) to a remote server. Just one domain for now (this is a test environment). Ive never used wix before. It looks promising, but I also can't imagine that there's nothing that is built into TFS for this already.

Comment: why don't you want robots.txt on dev/qa?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for packaging the files?

Meanwhile, not the best solution but you can always write a custom activity in your deployer build defintion to delete the robot.txt after deployment, if the environment is dev/QA.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **Deployment** project and then 
If you would like to exclude files from being included in the deployment, you
can use the **ExcludeFromBuild** item.

```
<ItemGroup>
<!-- Use the ExcludeFromBuild item to exclude files from being deployed -->
<ExcludeFromBuild
Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\WebApplication1.csproj" />
<ExcludeFromBuild
Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\WebApplication1.csproj.user" />
<ExcludeFromBuild
Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\CustomOut\**\*" />
<ExcludeFromBuild
Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\**\.svn\**\*" />
</ItemGroup>


<PropertyGroup>
<!-- Customize output location using the OutputPath property -->
<OutputPath>
```